Vite keeps using the old folder structure (Laravel & Inertia)
As per project reasons, I changed the usual Inertia Pages structure and I added the ability to load pages also from subfolder modules.
This is the usual app.js file:
// ...
createInertiaApp({
    title: (title) => `${title} - ${appName}`,
    resolve: (name) => resolvePageComponent(`./Pages/${name}.vue`, import.meta.glob('./Pages/**/*.vue')), 
// ...

And this is my current app.js file:
// ...
createInertiaApp({
    title: (title) => `${title} - ${appName}`,
    resolve(name) {
        const matched = /(.*)::/.exec(name);

        if (matched === null) {
            return import(`./Pages/${name}.vue`).then(module => module.default);
        }

        const module = matched[1];
        const pageName = name.replace(matched[0], "");

        return import(`./${module}/Pages/${pageName}.vue`).then(module => module.default);
    },
// ...

As you can see, if in controller I have return Inertia::render(ExampleModule::ExamplePage) it will return components/js/ExampleModule/Pages/ExamplePage.vue insted of components/js/Pages/ExampleModule::ExamplePage.vue.
This works well, the problem is I have the following 404 error in browser console due to vite trying to use the old folder structure.
GET https://laravel.test:5173/resources/js/Pages/ExampleModule::ExamplePage.vue net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Where I can find and change this configuration to match my actual folder structure rules?

I have a similar issue, only happening when running my tests in CI/CD. Did you find a solution ?

Not sure if it can fix your problem but by tweaking the config (php artisan vendor:publish --provider=Inertia\ServiceProvider) I was able to update the testing path to make it work
